# Загрузка сайта на хостинг(HTML,CSS,JS) и использование базы данных

Tags: javascript, база-данных

Пишу сайт с рецептами. на сайте будет возможность регистрации пользователей и они смогут выкладывать свои рецепты(изображения + текст). Сайт состоит из HTML,CSS,JS + должна быть база данных для хранения информации о пользователях и о рецептах.
Вопрос: как организовать взаимодействие сайта с БД и возможно ли так сделать? Если нет, то подскажите пожалуйста каким образом это устроить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для любого приложения, где требуется база данных необходим Back-End. Back-End пишется под веб обычно на языке программирования PHP. Хотя есть варианты написать на Python, NodeJs и т.п.
Совет: Если у Вас опыта нет такового и времени нет разбираться, используйте готовое решение в виде CMS. Например для Вашего формата может подойти WordPress. А с помощью Front-End (HTML+CSS+JS) можете задать свой интерфейс. Также можете поискать готовые решения скриптов специальных под Вашу тематику

Comment: Скажите, получается на сайте будут формы для заполнения(например регистрация пользователя). Пользователь вводит свои данные, я эти данные с помощью PHP вывожу и сохраняю в БД?

Comment: @GregoMur, Все верно. И не только регистрация, а также хранения рецептов их категории и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо Вам, буду пробовать)